# ACTION_CALL is not working in mobile but it is working in emulator

Tags: android

I am using Action_call for my app ,it is working fine in my emulator ,when i run the same code in my mobile it is not working and it is not opening the dialer pad 
I also took permission in manifest but no use. Here is the code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                String phNum = "tel:9741437389";
                myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phNum));
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: which version of android you are using in your mobile

Comment: What version of android device you are using

Comment: android 6.0.1 marshmellow

Comment: did you added run time permission

Answer (score 2):

ACTION_CALL and ACTION_DIAL is different thing in android.

```
1.in ACTION_CALL intent you are directly place call.

2.in ACTION_DIAL intent you call dial screen.
```

ACTION_DIAL never place call. in this you dont need to provide any permission.

Comment: in a real device?

Comment: in real device also same issue and now it is resolved

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if you are using the api version greater than 23 ,you need to provide the run time permission.

1) Please check if youy are using the api version 23 means add the run time permission.
  2) For addoing the run time permission please refer this sight.

http://www.truiton.com/2016/04/obtaining-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-6-0/

http://www.journaldev.com/10409/android-handling-runtime-permissions-example

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-marshmallow-permissions-example/